# Convert subprocess output to requests url

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the hostname by subprocess:

```
 hostname = str(subprocess.run(['hostname'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```

and then, use the hostname to create a new GET resust via requsts:

```
url=f"{server_url+str(host)}"
result = requests.get(url).json()
```

It didn't work for me and i recived an error:

```
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

somebody knows why?

TX

Answer (score 0):

It's worked for me after using:

```
url=f"{server_url+str(host).rstrip()}"
```